# Front End Ability to Change Category

Tags: wordpress, frontend, custom-post-type

So in wordpress I have a custom post type "wishlist" with the custom category taxonomies "private" and "shared" and I'm looking for a way to add a drop down menu on the front end that would allow the user the select from the two categories and hit submit and it would change the post category. Any clue how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `<select>` tag to be used in a form to make the UI. Once submit button is clicked, the default behavior of form takes all the data to server to a location provided in `action` attribute of the form.

An example code would be:

```
<form action="/location/on/server/">
<select>
<option value="private">private</option>
<option value="shared">shared</option>
</select>
```